# My script works perfectly, but since I have moved to another laptop

Tags: python, slack

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
#imports slack library

slack_client = SlackClient(“token is here hidden in this post”)
#API ACCESS

if __name__ == ’__main__‘:
api_call = slack_client.api_call(“users.list”)
#Pull’s a list of users from slack
if api_call.get(‘ok’):
    users = api_call.get(‘members’)
    for user in users:
        print(user[‘name’] + ' : ' + user.get(‘id’))
        #displays user names with according ID’s


member = raw_input (“Please type the ID of the member you would like to disable: “)

for user in users:
    if user.get(‘id’) == member:
        # disable account
        slack_client.api_call(
        ‘users.admin.setInactive’,
        user=member
        )
        print “User Disabled”
```

My code now pulls errors:

```
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier (line 5)
```

I don't understand why it does this, i've copied and pasted this from one laptop to another, what am i i missing?

Comment: You seem to be using "curly quotes", that's unlikely to work. Did you copy paste this via Word or something?

Comment: You have indentation problems too.

Comment: Actually that error usually means your identation is wrong. Is that all the error? The statement should be longer

Comment: line 27
    print "User Disabled"
                        ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("User Disabled")? I

Comment: I've checked the quotes that was a copy and paste error , but now my script isnt working? It was before on another laptop nothing else has changed.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient' , could I get a REAL answer please?

Comment: What's unclear from those error messages? Apparently you've moved to a computer with a different version of Python (3.x vs. 2.x) and without the right dependencies installed, so it shouldn't be too surprising that you don't get the same behaviour.

Comment: Same version of python on both 2.7

Comment: Path is probably wrong to the modules in intelliJ, any one know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The quotes `’` and `“` are not valid Python. Use `'` and `"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go through your code and replace all instances of single quotes and double quotes manually; something got messed up when you were copying/pasting.